# Missing menu items from the Apple Menu

Tags: finder, macos

Somehow in the past 24 hours, I have only a basic menu for the Apple Menu and my early 2011 MBP running Yosemite 10.10.1 also always starts up in the Simple Finder. I especially miss the Recent Items in the Apple Menu. No idea what happened.

When I login as a different user the Apple menu is "normal". How do I repair the broken user  Apple menu? Both user accounts I have are admin accounts. I tried turning off Parental Controls for the affected user account but Simple Finder persists

Comment: Is it the same if you log in as different user ?

Comment: Simple Finder is a Parental Control… Is your account an admin account?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a terminal command for changing the Simple Finder interface back to the Standard interface and it did the trick ;)

```
defaults write com.apple.finder InterfaceLevel standard;killall Finder
```

Got this from http://www.amsys.co.uk/2013/blog/how-to-quickly-enable-os-x-finders-simple-finder-mode/#.VI9WasZINv1

Thanks for the troubleshoot suggestions. It helped get me headed in the right direction.